# Provider: "Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the library **[Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)** like this:

```
runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      delegate,
      MyApp(
        localizedValues: {},
      ),
    ),
  );
```

and then:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, Map<String, String>> localizedValues;
  MyApp({required this.localizedValues});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyRents()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: initialRoute,
    localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      localizationDelegate
    ],
```

This is my provider:

```
class MyRents extends ChangeNotifier {
// LIST OF VARS NOT USED AT THIS POINT

  bool loadingUserInfo = false;
  var language;
  // List list = rentsList;
  List list = [];
  int currentPortfolioIndex = 0;
  int currenRentIndex = 0;
  var clonedRent;
  List newGalleryImages = []; // local gallery images that we haven't pushed yet
  SharedPreferences? prefs;
  String viewMode = 'multi';
  bool galleryScrollView = true;
  PageController portfolioController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  MyUser? user; // TODO: move this to a separate provider
  List<ProductDetails> products = [];
  List<PurchaseDetails> purchases = [];
  bool showAds = false;
  Map companyInfo = {};
  List withholdings = [];
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> taxes = [];
// END LIST


  // MyRents(); // TODO: check null (this was working in Flutter 1 but not now so it might be related to the error)...
  final MyRents myRents = MyRents(); // ...and this is the Flutter 2 version

  updateUI() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final MyRents myRents = MyRents();
```

This was working well in Flutter 1 but I'm getting this error now in Flutter 2:

> Reassembling main.dart$main-2339422228391703 failed:
> ext.flutter.reassemble: (-32000) Server error {"exception":"Bad state:
> Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its
> value.\nThe exception occurred during the creation of type
> MyRents.","stack":"#0      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value
> (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:661:7)\n#1
> _InheritedProviderScopeElement.reassemble (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:367:60)\n#2
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#3
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#4
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#5
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#6
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#7
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#8
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#9
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#10
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#11
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#12
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#13
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#14
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#15
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#16
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#17
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#18
> ComponentElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:14)\n#19
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#20
> StatefulElement.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4624:11)\n#21
> Element.reassemble.
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3072:13)\n#22
> RenderObjectToWidgetElement.visitChildren
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1139:14)\n#23
> Element.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3071:5)\n#24
> BuildOwner.reassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2892:12)\n#25
> WidgetsBinding.performReassemble
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:951:19)\n#26
> BindingBase.lockEvents
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:298:41)\n#27
> BindingBase.reassembleApplication
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:338:12)\n#28
> BindingBase.registerSignalServiceExtension.
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:375:23)\n#29
> BindingBase.registerSignalServiceExtension.
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:374:17)\n#30
> BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:597:32)\n\n","method":"ext.flutter.reassemble"}

and this other one:

> ======== Exception caught by Flutter framework ===================================================== The following StateError was thrown during a service extension callback for
> "ext.flutter.reassemble": Bad state: Tried to read a provider that
> threw during the creation of its value. The exception occurred during
> the creation of type MyRents.

Comment: Please post the`MyRents` provider. The error was throne during building it.

Comment: done. I removed some unnecessary code. Nothing was being called at that point (I guess)

Comment: "Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value." the error shows up over there. You can use a final variable over build or didChangeDependencies if the variable you have for that class is null.

Comment: comment this out `final MyRents myRents = MyRents();,` and Use this `ChangeNotifierProvider<MyRents>(create: (_) => MyRents())`,, also where are you calling your values to listen to?

Comment: Something was being called, and that is your provider class, telling it to instantiate MyRents()

Comment: Show where the value you are calling.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad that worked. Feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment this out

`final MyRents myRents = MyRents();`  and also use this

`ChangeNotifierProvider<MyRents>(create: (_) => MyRents())`

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen if you are utilising GetIt, maybe you forgot to initialize it in the first main() before runApp()